# Adding row to a table and getting it reflected in the other table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 sheets in the same workbook. Lets say Data  and Report. Data is input sheet while Report is the output sheet where some cells are directly linked to Data and others have some calculation based formulas. I have converted the content in both sheets to Table so that on inserting row, formula is automatically copied from the previous row.
My question: Is there a way I can add row to the sheet Data, input values there and a corresponding row gets added at the same spot to the sheet Report with formulas as in previous row? I am not very good with macros. Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `=IFERROR(Table1[@columnName],"")` on the Report sheet. `Table1` would need to be the table name from the Data sheet. `@columnName` would be the name of the column from the table on the Data sheet. You would then just copy the formula all the way down the columns on the Report sheet. This, of course, only works if you don't require a table on the Report sheet. This is the onyl way I can think of without use of macros.